# MyriadPro mathlf

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm trying to get `mathlf` option working for MyriadPro (installed with FontPro).

Here is a working preamble for `lf`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[medfamily,math,lf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
```

However, a subtitution of `lf` with `mathlf` which I would expect to keep just Lining figures for math mode, isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beamer`, by default, changes the math font set-up to get acceptable sans serif math symbols. Use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` to disable that. Thus, use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[medfamily,math,mathlf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
```